# Cambiar de tamaño un JScrollBar Java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, jtable

Buenas tardes compañeros, hoy tengo una pregunta que me ha reventado la cabeza casi por una hora creyendo que era algo sencillo.

Tengo un jtable con su respectivo jscrollbar.

Y agregue un boton para que la tabla pueda cambiar de tamaño a uno más grande (sin maximizar la ventana).

El layout padre es absoluto y el código del evento es.

```
private void btnMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int posicion = btnMenu.getX();
        if (posicion>5) {
            Animacion.Animacion.mover_izquierda(-5, -255, 5, 5, pnlMenu);
            Animacion.Animacion.mover_izquierda(240, 0, 5, 5, btnMenu);
            Animacion.Animacion.mover_izquierda(245, 20, 5, 5, jScrollPane2);
            //jScrollPane2.setBounds(20, 60, 2000, 820);
            jScrollPane2.setSize(new Dimension(1265, 820));
            jScrollPane2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1265, 820));
            jScrollPane2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1265, 820));
        } else {
            Animacion.Animacion.mover_derecha(-255, -5, 5, 5, pnlMenu);
            Animacion.Animacion.mover_derecha(0, 240, 5, 5, btnMenu);
            Animacion.Animacion.mover_derecha(20, 245, 5, 5, jScrollPane2);
            //jScrollPane2.setBounds(245, 60, 1020, 820);
            jScrollPane2.setSize(new Dimension(1020, 820));
            jScrollPane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1020, 820));
        }
    }
```

De manera resumida tengo un boton inicial en una posicion X, que cuando lo oprimo acciona un efecto de desplazamiento en el menu (escondiendose a la izquierda), posteriormente tambien se desplaza la tabla o más precisamente el scrollpane (tambien a la izquierda) y hasta aqui todo funciona.

Lo siguiente que queria era la tabla cambiara de tamaño para que aumentara su ancho y ocupara de mejor manera el panel.

He intentado con todos los metodos que pueden ver empezando desde el setBounds y ninguno funciona. La tabla simplemente se desplaza la izquierda pero no cambia de tamaño.

Sería de gran ayuda que me pudiesen ayudar.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola primero puedes intentar agregar tu `Jtable` a tu ScrollPane

```
jScrollPane2.setViewportView(table);
```

depues en tu evento cambias las dimensiones de tu ScrollPane y luego vuelve agregar el `jtable` y esto hará que tu `Jtable` se re dimensione de acuerdo a tu scrollpane.

```
private void btnMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
        jScrollPane2.setSize(1020, 820);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(table);
}
```

Comment: Te mereces un premio amigo! Funcionó perfecto!